# What's the function of toString in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tostring

I know that it makes a number to a string but where should it be used?

Comment: Better to read [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). `MDN` contains comprehensive information regarding `toString`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString maybe more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need convert objects  or .json to string, and well in.that moment .toString() is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Let put it in specific cases:

- When I work with adding 2 number or adding 2 string

  `var num1 = 25`

  `var num2 = 30`

if I wanted to join 2 number to string `2530` then I would use
`num1.toString() + num2.toString()`

- When I need to parse a JSON to a string:

when I need to save a request body (JSON body of course) for audit purpose, I can use toString() on that object and save that string.

And many more... (I will update if I think of something)